# ValueError: Error when checking target: expected PREDICTIONS to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (20, 131) [Keras]

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, output, conv-neural-network

I am trying to train pre-trained MobileNet version 2  model on Fruits-360 dataset (https://github.com/Horea94/Fruit-Images-Dataset) by fine-tuning the model with the classes provided in the dataset. While training my custom model it is throwing the following error for **model.fit_generator()**:

> ValueError: Error when checking target: expected PREDICTIONS to have 4
>   dimensions, but got array with shape (20, 131)

Any idea where I might be going wrong and how I can fix it?

My python code containing the fine-tuned model as follows:

```
import os
import glob
import sys

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.applications.mobilenet_v2 import MobileNetV2
from keras.models import Model
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.applications.mobilenet_v2 import preprocess_input, decode_predictions
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, EarlyStopping, CSVLogger

import PIL
from PIL import Image
import requests
from io import BytesIO
from keras.layers import Dense, GlobalAveragePooling2D, GlobalMaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dropout

def list_dirs(path):
    return [os.path.basename(x) for x in filter(
        os.path.isdir, glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*')))]

labels = list_dirs("Path_to_dataset/fruits-360/Training")
labels.sort()

epochs = 100

# Base directory of raw jpg/png images
base_dir = 'Path_to_dataset/fruits-360'

train_path = os.path.join(base_dir, 'Training')
nb_train_samples = 67692
valid_path = os.path.join(base_dir, 'Test')
nb_val_samples = 22688
test_path = os.path.join(base_dir, 'test-multiple_fruits')

batch_size = 20

train_steps = nb_train_samples // batch_size
valid_steps = nb_val_samples // batch_size

classes = labels

img_width, img_height = 224, 224

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)
val_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_path, target_size=(img_width, img_height),
                                                    classes=classes, class_mode='categorical',
                                                    batch_size=batch_size)
val_generator = val_datagen.flow_from_directory(valid_path, target_size=(img_width, img_height),
                                                    classes=classes, class_mode='categorical',
                                                    batch_size=batch_size)

base_model = MobileNetV2(weights='imagenet', include_top=True)

x = base_model.layers[-6].output
predictions = Dense(len(classes), activation='softmax', name='PREDICTIONS')(x)
model = Model(input=base_model.input, outputs=predictions)

for layer in model.layers[:-5]:
    layer.trainable = False

model.compile(optimizer=SGD(lr=0.0001, momentum=0.9),
                  loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()

model.fit_generator(train_generator, epochs= epochs,
                                      steps_per_epoch=train_steps,
                                      validation_data = val_generator,
                                      validation_steps= valid_steps)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue happens because the output of "*x = base_model.layers[-6].output*" is different from the input of "*Dense(len(classes), activation='softmax', name='PREDICTIONS')(x)*". This can be resolved by including the following line of code, which is a flatten layer, used to flatten the input:

```
x = Flatten(name='FLATTEN')(x)
```

The code for the model is as follows:

base_model = MobileNetV2(weights='imagenet', include_top=True)

```
x = base_model.layers[-6].output
x = Flatten(name='FLATTEN')(x)
predictions = Dense(len(classes), activation='softmax', name='PREDICTIONS')(x)
model = Model(input=base_model.input, outputs=predictions)
```